# How do I make Arduino IDE use a specific version of GCC in Debian?

Tags: arduino-ide, compile, raspberrypi, gcc

Using Raspbian Stretch.

I installed gcc-4.9 with specified version. Then I installed arduino (2.1.0.5) which in turn pulled gcc 4.6. When I try to compile [Marlin](https://reprap.org/wiki/Marlin) in it, it says

> Marlin requires C++11 support (gcc >= 4.7, Arduino IDE >= 1.6.8).
>   Please upgrade your toolchain.

How do I make Arduino IDE use the correct version of GCC?

Comment: I think this is a question to ask on Debian forum and not here.

Comment: Why on earth did you install such an ancient version? Delete it and download the *current* (i.e., released *this decade*) version.

Comment: @Majenko, these are the newest versions. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gcc https://packages.debian.org/stretch/arduino

Comment: No, those are versions that were submitted to Debian years ago. You don't install Arduino from the Debian repositories. You haven't done for many many years. Download the Arduino IDE from the Arduino website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Majenko [pointed out](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54792/how-do-i-make-arduino-ide-use-a-specific-version-of-gcc-in-debian#comment115148_54792), I should have used a tarball from the [official site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) instead of the repositories. Which makes me wonder why that package wasn't deprecated or something...

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Arduino package from the Debian repository (or the one for derived distros like Ubuntu) performs the useful purpose of setting up all the necessary permissions for the Arduino IDE to work. Those permissions are NOT automatically removed when you uninstall the package.

The simplest way to get a working Arduino install:

1. Install Arduino from the repo

2. Immediately uninstall it

3. Get a current version of Arduino from arduino.cc and install that